# How to used sdaps setuptex command in python program

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I used `sdaps` command `setup_tex` to create a sdaps project in linux command line:

```
kashif@crunchbang:~$ sdaps /tmp/project setup_tex example.tex
```

which created project directory successfully, Now i want to use this command in my python program by executing this instruction:

```
sdaps.setuptex.setup.setup(survey, cmdline)
```

but don't know what exactly argument I should give to successfully execute to create project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow i manage to create project by using os package i.e

import os

os.system("sdaps /tmp/project setup_tex example.tex")

but still i need standard documentation of sdaps usage with example so that i could make my own changes.